# get new Instance for function each test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have some tests in one file,

I check my reducer with some case

My code looks like this

`my code`

```js
import axiosInstance from '~/utils/network';
const fetcher = axiosInstance();


const fetchMiddleware = () => {
  switch (type) {

     case 'LOGOUT':{
      try {
          await fetcher.get(API.GET.LOGOUT_OPERATION);

          dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS' });
        } catch (err) {
          dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT_FAIL' });
        }
      });
     }
   }
}
```

`my test`

```js
import axiosInstance from '../../src/utils/network';

import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

const middlewares = [fetchMiddleware, thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
const store = mockStore(getInitialReducerState());


jest.mock('../../src/utils/network', () => {
  const axiosInstance = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      get: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
          headers: {},
        };
      }),
    };
  }) as any;
  axiosInstance.configure = jest.fn();
  return axiosInstance;
});


describe('test LOGOUT', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    store.clearActions();
  });

  it('should test be success', async () => {
    await store.dispatch({
      type: 'LOGOUT',
      payload: { userName: 'testUserName' },
    });

    expect(store.getActions()).toContainEqual({
      type: 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS',
    });
  });

  it('should test be fail', async () => {
    (axiosInstance as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        get: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
          throw new Error(' ');
        }),
      };
    });
    await store.dispatch({
      type: 'LOGOUT',
      payload: { userName: 'testUserName' },
    });

    expect(store.getActions()).toContainEqual({
      type: 'LOGOUT_FAIL',
    });
  });
});
```

I want to test two scenarios: success & fail,

I mock the `axiosInstance` function.

But even I override the mock in the second test I get the first mock because my code loads `axiosInstance` only once.

what can I do?

Comment: Went back and forth between a comment and an answer. Decided it's definitely a comment. I strongly suggest [moxios](https://github.com/axios/moxios) if you haven't already. Less of your own manual mock code to maintain. Good docs, set up should be easy.

Comment: How does the fetchMiddleware is used?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use [`jest.isolateModules`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestisolatemodulesfn)**

---

Let's say we have 2 files:

1. `./lib.js` - this is your `~/utils/network`
2. `./repro.js` - this is your file with the code under test

**`./lib.js`:**

```js
export default function lib() {
  return () => 10;
}
```

**`./repro.js`:**

```js
import lib from './lib';
const fnInstance = lib();

export const fn = () => {
  return fnInstance();
};
```

**And the `./repro.test.js`:**

```js
function getRepro(libMock) {
  let repro;

  // Must use isolateModules because we need to require a new module everytime
  jest.isolateModules(() => {
    jest.mock('./lib', () => {
      return {
        default: libMock,
      };
    });

    repro = require('./repro');
  });

  // If for some reason in the future the behavior will change and this assertion will fail
  // We can do a workaround by returning a Promise and the `resolve` callback will be called with the Component in the `isolateModules` function
  // Or we can also put the whole test function inside the `isolateModules` (less preferred)
  expect(repro).toBeDefined();

  return repro;
}

describe('', () => {
  it('should return 1', () => {
    const { fn } = getRepro(function lib() {
      return () => 1
    });
    expect(fn()).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('should return 2', () => {
    const { fn } = getRepro(function lib() {
      return () => 2
    });

    expect(fn()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: isolateModules is overkill here. The module doesn't need to be reevaluated.

Comment: I would like to hear an alternative

Comment: Mocked axiosInstance should return an object of spies that can change the implementation on the fly. isolateModules is needed when imported value is scalar or produces side effects.

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to use existing library to mock Axios, it saves from boilerplate code and potential mistakes in mock implementation; `moxios` has been already suggested.

It's inconvenient to mock `axiosInstance` per test because it has been already called on the import of tested module, so this requires it to be re-imported per test; another answer explains how it's done with `jest.isolateModules`.

Since `axiosInstance` is evaluated only once and is supposed to return mocked object, it's convenient to mock it once per test and then change implementations:

```
jest.mock('~/utils/network', () => {
  const axiosMock = { get: jest.fn(), ... };
  return {
    axiosInstance: () => axiosMock;
  };
});

const axiosMock = axiosInstance();

...

(axiosMock.get axiosInstance as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => {
  throw new Error(' ');
});

await store.dispatch(...);
```

This requires to use `jest.restoreAllMocks` in `beforeEach` or similar Jest configuration option to avoid test cross-contamination.

Notice that Axios doesn't throw errors but rather return rejected promises, this may affect test results, see the note regarding the benefits of libraries.